# How to remove extra space inside the bootstrap row

Tags: javascript, php, css, bootstrap-5

I want ro remove this extra space i am using bootstrap 5 version
i tried bootstrap classes like pr-0,mr-0,p-auto,m-auto but there but there were no changes.
then i tried css margin-right:0; this is also didn't work

i added some background colors to find column boarders.

[image: 1 screenshot]

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10 bg-info">
    <div class="row mt-3 ">
      <div class=" col-md-6 bg-success mr-auto">
        <label for="">വഴിപാട്</label>
        <select name="vazhipad" id="vazhipad" class=" form-control">
          <option value="">പുഷ്പാജ്ഞലി</option>
          <option value="">അർച്ചന</option>
          <option value="">കൂവളമാല</option>
          <option value="">രക്തപുഷ്പാജ്ഞലി</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 bg-warning">
        <label for="">എണ്ണം</label>
        <input type="number" name="ennam" id="ennam" class=" form-control" disabled value="1">
      </div>
      <div class=" col-md-3 bg-primary mr-0">
        <label for="">തുക</label>
        <input type="number" name="thuka-table" id="thuka-table" class=" form-control " disabled>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-3 ">
      <div class=" col-md-6">
        {{-- <label for="">വഴിപാട്</label> --}}
        <select name="vazhipad" id="vazhipad" class=" form-control">
          <option value="">പുഷ്പാജ്ഞലി</option>
          <option value="">അർച്ചന</option>
          <option value="">കൂവളമാല</option>
          <option value="">രക്തപുഷ്പാജ്ഞലി</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="number" name="ennam" id="ennam" class=" form-control" disabled value="1">
      </div>
      <div class=" col-md-2">
        {{-- <label for="">തുക</label> --}}
        <input type="number" name="thuka-table" id="thuka-table" class=" form-control " disabled>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-3 ">
      <div class=" col-md-6">
        {{-- <label for="">വഴിപാട്</label> --}}
        <select name="vazhipad" id="vazhipad" class=" form-control">
          <option value="">പുഷ്പാജ്ഞലി</option>
          <option value="">അർച്ചന</option>
          <option value="">കൂവളമാല</option>
          <option value="">രക്തപുഷ്പാജ്ഞലി</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="number" name="ennam" id="ennam" class=" form-control" disabled value="1">
      </div>
      <div class=" col-md-2">
        {{-- <label for="">തുക</label> --}}
        <input type="number" name="thuka-table" id="thuka-table" class=" form-control " disabled>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have the blue area on the right because you’ve created a new row and filled it with only 11 columns (6 + 2 + 3). If you don’t want the blue area, you need to make the three columns inside the row add up to 12.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you increase the second column to col-md-3

```
<div class="col-md-3 bg-warning">
```

[image]

also you can offsetting column

```
<div class="col-md-2 bg-warning offset-md-1">
```

[image]

Read more about offsetting columns [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/#offsetting-columns)